# JS Автообновление диалога

Tags: php, javascript, html

Столкнулась с проблемой обновления блока, в котором отображаю сообщения

Вызываю функцию и передаю в нее id, но блок не обновляется по заданному времени

```
<a href"#" onclick="msgUpd('<?=$conv['id']?>');" >

<script>
var id;
function msgUpd(id) {    
    $(".comments-list").load("/getpm/"+id);
    usrto = $("#usrto").val();
    cid = $("#cid").val();
    $("#user_to").val(usrto);
    $("#conversation_id").val(cid);
}
setInterval(msgUpd, 3000);
</script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это решить?

Comment: setInterval(msgUpd(id), 3000);

Comment: @KirillKorushkin этот вариант я пробовала, он тоже не работает

Comment: а чито в консольке есть?

Comment: А ничего, что `setInterval(function() { msgUpd(id) }, 3000)` ?

Comment: @selya  не смешно

Comment: @Елизавета id какое-то значение присваивается?

Comment: `onclick="msgUpd('<?=$conv['id']?>');"` тут вы вызываете функцию по клику и передаете в нее строку. А ваш `setInterval` вызывает эту функцию без аргументов. Как думаете, может в этом проблема?)

Comment: @KirillKorushkin консольку, к сожалению, не могу посмотреть, я заблокировала доступ извне, и работаю только через приложение. Значение берется из цикла, как id диалога, далее, я подгружаю все сообщения из таблицы с id диалога и пытаюсь повесить подгрузку, но функция молчит.. Я сейчас попробую попасть в консоль, гляну и отпишусь

Comment: В любом случае запись setInterval(msgUpd(id), 3000) маст хев, ибо когда вы функцию декларируете, вы ей говорите принимать параметр. А при вызове в сетИнтервал параметр не передаёте. Первый раз от клика она срабатывает, т.к. получает id, а в сетИнтервал  - нет.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да, она долбит по неизвестному id, но такой вариант (msgUpd(id)  не работает, получается, мне нужно передать значение напрямую ?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я прошу прощения. Либо я что-то совсем не догоняю, либо вы не правы. Когда вы передадите ваш `msgUpd(id)`, вы просто вызовете функцию `msgUpd(id)`. Она вернет вам ничего (`undefined`), и этот андефайнд вы передадите в `setInterval`. Разве я не прав?

Comment: @selya именно так, я не могу понять, как текущее значение отправить на перезагрузку

Comment: @Елизавета добавил ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут вы вызываете `msgUpd` с аргументом `'<?=$conv['id']?>'`:

```
onclick="msgUpd('<?=$conv['id']?>');"
```

Могу предположить, что этот вызов работает.

А в `setInterval` вы передаете вашу функцию `msgUpd` без аргументов:

```
setInterval(msgUpd, 3000);
```

И `setInterval` ее, соответственно, вызывает без аргументов.

Такой вариант из комментариев не подойдет:

```
setInterval(msgUpd(id), 3000);
```

Ибо тогда вы вызовете `msgUpd` единожды с аргументом `id`. Функция вернет `undefined`, который вы и передадите в качестве первого аргумента для `setInterval`.

Если вам нужно отправить на перезагрузку последнее значение `id`, поправьте ваш код:

```
var lastId;

function msgUpd(id) {    
    $(".comments-list").load("/getpm/"+id);
    usrto = $("#usrto").val();
    cid = $("#cid").val();
    $("#user_to").val(usrto);
    $("#conversation_id").val(cid);
    lastId = id;
}

setInterval(function() { msgUpd(lastId) }, 3000);
```

Внутри функции `msgUpd` сохраняем переданный аргумент `id` в переменную `lastId`. А для `setInterval` передаем аргумент `function() { msgUpd(lastId) }` - функция, внутри которой мы вызываем `msgUpd` с аргументом, в котором уже есть сохраненный последний `id`.

Comment: Да, именно так! Спасибо Большое!

Comment: @Елизавета кстати, в `setInterval` можно передавать аргументы для вызываемой функции после указания `delay`.... таким образом можно написать и `setInterval(msgUpd, 3000, lastId);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нельзя. Параметр же передастся по значению. И когда обновится значение `lastId`, то этого обновления `setInterval` не передаст. Или же я не прав?

Comment: @selya запустите в консоли `var i = 0;
function test () {
 console.log(i++);
}

setInterval(test, 1000, i);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы шутите? У вас функция `test` вообще не принимает параметров. А внутри обращается к глобальной переменной `i`. Запустите хоть ваш пример, хоть так: `var i = 0; function test () { console.log(i++); } setInterval(test, 1000);` - все равно будет выводить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для подтверждения моих слов запустите `var i = 0; setInterval(function() { i = i + 1 }, 1000); setInterval(console.log, 1000, i);`. Один сетИнтервал обновляет переменную, второй выводит как вы предложили. И выводит он постоянно то значение, которое передали в него в момент инициализации.

Comment: @selya не в обиду, но вам учить матчасть. Обязательно. С уважением.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin объясните же, что не так. Может я в упор не вижу, ибо сутки не спал. Может я сейчас сам просвещусь. Не лишайте меня возможности улучшить свои познания.

Comment: @selya в вашем ответе всё верно. Но в комментах вы много тупили там-сям =) Ночная работа она такая, знаю ;)

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Так я и спрашиваю, что в комментариях было не так... Без стеба же... Мне важно понимать, что я делаю не так. Или вы в целом про термины? Это я мог, это мне думать лень